# Iterate over attributes of an XML Element

Tags: xml, powershell

XML Document:

```
<components one="true" two="false" three="1.0.1" four="3.0" five="true"/>
```

With PowerShell, how can I dynamically loop through the different attributes in the `components` element. Keeping in mind that the attributes could be different every time the code executes.  I can "hard-code" the attribute names, etc. but that's not efficient, would have to constantly update as new components are added/removed.

Answer (score 1):

Cribbed from [this page](http://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2007/12/02/parsing-xml-files-with-powershell/) and adjusted to extract attributes instead of elements:

```
...
[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $xd = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$file = resolve-path("yourfile.xml")
$xd.load($file)
$nodelist = $xd.selectnodes("/components/@*") # XPath is case sensitive
foreach ($attr in $nodelist) {
    ...
```

Note: I know nothing about PowerShell, but just by pattern matching and assuming that Microsoft's XPath works like standard XPath, you should be able to create a nodelist containing attribute nodes.  Even if this doesn't work exactly as written, it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks I was able to loop through the attributes and get the value - still need to display the attribute name now..                     $nodelist = $xml.selectnodes("/configurationDocument/dotnetDeployableAsset/components/@*")
foreach ($attr in $nodelist) {
    $attr
}

Comment: The DOM has a `name()` function to get a node's name.

Answer (score 1):

What about

`([xml]$(Get-Content .\yourfile.xml)).components`

which will give you following output

```
one   : true
two   : false
three : 1.0.1
four  : 3.0
five  : true
```

If you want more controll over the results, try this:

```
foreach ($attr in ([xml]$(Get-Content .\yourfile.xml)).components.attributes)
{
$attr.Name #Attribute Name
$attr."#text" #Attribute Value
}
```